# Module version is always 0.0, even when ModuleVersion is defined?

Tags: powershell

I created a module using [these instructions](https://www.scriptrunner.com/en/blog/building-your-first-powershell-module/), which worked great. I can run `Get-Command -Module <module name>` or `Get-Module -Name <module name>` and see the module and its commands.

The only problem is with both of the above commands, the module version and command versions always say `0.0`:

```
PS > Get-Command -Module Confluence

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Add-ConfluenceAttachment                           0.0        Confluence
Function        Find-ConfluencePage                                0.0        Confluence
Function        Get-BasicAuthCredential                            0.0        Confluence
Function        Get-ConfluenceAttachment                           0.0        Confluence
Function        Get-ConfluenceItem                                 0.0        Confluence
Function        New-ConfluencePage                                 0.0        Confluence
Function        Set-ConfluencePage                                 0.0        Confluence


PS > Get-Module -Name Confluence

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0        Confluence                          {Add-ConfluenceAttachment, Find-...
```

In the manifest file (`Confluence.psd1`), however, I've got the following line:

```
ModuleVersion = '1.0'
```

I've tried changing it to a different number and I've tried making it an integer instead of a string, but no change.

So what's the correct way to update the version number for a module and its functions/cmdlets?

Comment: Are you using `Import-Module -Force` to reload the module?

Comment: I used it with and without `-Force`

Comment: Are you pointing `Import-Module` to the `psm1` or `psd1` file?

Comment: I'm pointing it to the `psm1` file. I just tried pointing it to the `psd1` file and that did it! thanks for the help. Feel free to submit that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Try using `Remove-Module -Name Confluence` before `Import-Module`. Alternatively, start a new PowerShell console and import the module.

Comment: It's the `psd1` the one having the reference of your module version as well as all metadata about it ;) feel free to post a self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was originally importing the `psm1` file, but once I imported the `psd1` file, the version reflected correctly:

```
PS > Import-Module Confluence.psd1

PS > Get-Module -Name Confluence

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     1.0        Confluence                          {Add-ConfluenceAttachment, Find-...
```